# Why do i get this error in the build.gradle file?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, build.gradle

The error is FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

"* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.1/gradle-8.1.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.1/gradle-8.1.pom
> Required by:
> project :

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 2s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              3,3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1"

Eventough i fix this error i get different errors and unable to write any code. Plesase comment if you have any permanent solutions. My files are below: (Gradle 8.1), (openjdk 17.0.6)

build.gradle/app

```
plugins{
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
}
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.food"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.food"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.3.1')
    implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics')
}
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.1-all.zip
```

I tried updating and also downgrading the gradle but still did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I managed to fix it by changing `compileSdkVersion`, `minSdkVersion`, and `targetSdkVersion`.

app/build.gradle

```
android {
  ...
  compileSdkVersion 34
  ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
}


defaultConfig {
  ...
  minSdkVersion 21
  targetSdkVersion 34
}
```

I'm not sure if it'll fix yours because I'm using `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'`
maybe try downgrade or for 8.1.x try reference [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle/8.1.0) and [here](https://gradle.org/releases/)

Comment: Thank you. I will try and get back to you

Comment: now I get the following error when i changed the sdk versions, Exception: [!] Your app is using an unsupported Gradle project. To fix this problem, create a new project by running `flutter create -t app <app-directory>`
and then move the dart code, assets and pubspec.yaml to the new project.

Comment: have you tried `flutter create .` ?

Comment: yeah i did, it did not work either